# odbc_fetch_array returns garbled value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks for a result.  The query itself works fine in Microsoft SQL Server Management, so I know it isn't the query itself.  All I can think is it is some nuance with how I'm returning the result.

```
$Degree1 = '';
$queryDegree1 = 'SELECT TOP (1) [Degree] FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Education] WHERE [Person2ID] = 454 AND [Rank] = 1';
$resultDegree1 = odbc_exec($connection, $queryDegree1) or die(odbc_errormsg());
if ($resultDegree1) {
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array( $resultDegree1 )) {
        $Degree1 = $row['Degree'];
    }
}
```

When I echo `$Degree1`, it spits out: `�!�7.0;���\Pro���������x86)���\v7.���\Win���;C:\���ows��`.

I expect the value to be `PhD, Chemistry, University at City`

The column itself is varchar(max), which I use for other columns in other tables in the same database, and those return the values perfectly fine.

Comment: Inside the `while` loop, put this line `var_dump($row);` en add the output to your question.

Comment: Var_dump gives: array(1) {
  ["Degree"]=>
  string(66) "�@x`E���were��������RE0.15���tor����������������EST_�"

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up deleting the table and re-creating it.  I then modified my insert query to make sure I included N'[value]'.  That seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: The `N` was probably the problem. The fact the string comes back garbled also may imply a [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) issue.